# How to ping or check status of WCF service using net.tcp endpoint from remote server?

Tags: .net, wcf

I really come from the world of `Http` and never did much with the old .NET Remoting which used TCP, but I understand the TCP concepts and now have implemented several WCF services using the net.tcp binding over the last few years. Most of the time it is up, running, I consume it, end of story. However sometimes the server setup is more advanced and I get communication errors that exist on 1 server and maybe not from another. To prove if it is a firewall/server/etc. issue I need to see if the WCF service can even be seen or reached without issue. This is for a Windows Service hosted WCF service using net.tcp that I am trying to figure out this situation.

The thing is with a WCF service exposed via a HTTP binding, I can just plop the URI in the browser to view the service page letting me know the service is running properly. Easy test.

How do I do the equivalent for a WCF service exposed via a net.tcp binding? Is there any tool or command I can use to test for example `net.tcp//mycustomWCFService:8123/MyService` ? I have seen a few posts on writing code to programmatically determine if the WCF service is available but I do not want to do it this way. I want to do this check if at all possible *without* code, analogous to me pulling up the http endpoint in a browser.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I am also wondering to solve same kind of issue. I am not sure whether WC service is runnning or not?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If your service implements a metadata endpoint (typically named `mex` and nested beneath the principal endpoint, implemented using the `mexTcpBinding` in this case), you can "ping" it using the svcutil command line utility that's provided with Visual Studio.  E.g.,

```
svcutil net.tcp://mycustomWCFService:8123/MyService/mex
```

If it throws an error, your service is (potentially) down.  If it succeeds, you're (likely) in business.  As the preceding parentheticals suggest, it's an approximation.  It means there's a listener at the address and that it's able to service a metadata request.

Comment: If I am on a remote server where Visual Studio was not installed, would the svcutil.exe utility still be installed?

Comment: No, it would not, but it doesn't have any dependencies that I'm aware of so as long as you can copy it to the remote server you would be in business.

Comment: I think I could wrap the call up using code and a small WinForms app using the svcutil.exe as a dependency to streamline this best. Thanks for the suggestion. Enjoy the extra 50 points!!!

Comment: Do you have another option? I am looking at a very restricted server, where I can't install anything

Comment: to use this command you need to append the PATH in environment variable, check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420354/vs2010-svcutil-exe-command-not-recognized/39494021

Answer (score 35):

Another way I found to at least see if it is listening is to issue the following 'netstat' command (from a command prompt) on the installed server:

**netstat -ona | find "8123"**

(Yes that is a pipe delimiter in the command above). If anything is returned it is actively listening and hosted on the searched port.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way of doing that would be (assuming the service is hosted in IIS) to add a HTTP binding (using a different port!!) to the same IIS site and to add `<serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" />` to the service behaviors. That way you can easily check that the service is up by navigating to its HTTP URL in a browser. Admittedly, that way you can only find out whether the service is up or not, you wouldn't be able to detect any networking issues on the particular TCP port, for instance.

If you need to address the latter issue as well, or if adding a HTTP binding is not possible you could just add a simple "PING" operation to the service contract and use a net.tcp client to invoke that one.

Comment: Good idea for IIS hosted sites originally only using a net.tcp binding as you mentioned, but for my scenario I was speaking more along the lines of a WCF service hosted in a Windows Service using net.tcp. I edited the OP to include this info.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the telnet client program to discover listening ports, i.e., telnet {url or IP} {port}.  To check if a web site is up.. 'telnet www.godaddy.com 80' should initially produce a blank window followed by a Request Time-out response (400) if no commands follow.