# VS2010 SvcUtil.exe command not recognized

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I am attempted to generate a proxy through the SvcUtil.Exe tool that if offered on the visual studio command line. I have checked in the default directory where this resides, and I have seen that the executable is there in the following directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin
```

I have my client which I am attempting to generate a proxy for at

```
C:\Users\Eric\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WcfServiceConsole
```

As directed by MSDN, I have navigated to the directory of my client, and I have used the following command:

```
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs /config: app.config http:
//localhost:8000/service
```

I am getting the usual error response from the command line:

```
"svcutil.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program
 or batch file".
```

What can I do sot hat I can navigate to my project's solution, and then use this tool?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can either set the path of the svcutil that you want to use in the path variables, or specify the full path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs /config: app.config http:
//localhost:8000/service

Comment: The point is that you can run either from either location.  Either use the location of the svcutil and specify the full location of the wsdl or use the location of the wsdl and specify the full location of the svcutil.

Comment: I would also use the Visual Studio Command Prompt which has most paths already specified in the environment variables when it is launched. It will save you a lot of hassle most times.

Comment: I am using the Visual Studio Command prompt, and I specified the full path of the SvcUtil.exe but it is telling me the C:\Program Files is not recognized...not sure why...If i were to add the SvcUtil.exe, I would just add the full path of the variable as an environment variable right?

Comment: Add quotes around the path, it stops at the first space. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\svcutil.exe" /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs /config: app.config http: //localhost:8000/service

Comment: I think it recognized it after that...getting a different error, but i think it solved the problem! Thanks

Comment: Yeah it wouldn't let me accept it before, but I was wondering, do you see a problem with the command, it is telling me "the filename, directory, or volume label syntax is incorrect?" I would appreciate it, I know its different problem, just trying to avoid a new post!

Answer (score 6):

To set this path permanently in your command prompt:

Go to Control Panel >> System >> Advanced Tab >> Environment Variables

[image: System Properties in Control Panel]

In System Variables, select the PATH row and click Edit:

[image]

Then, paste the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\ and click Ok:

[image]

Now, you can use the command without typing the full directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed any Version of Visual Studio, just open the "Developer Command Prompt" which comes by default with a lot of development tools like "svcutil":

[image]

The "Developer Command Prompt" is the same as a normal "cmd" window, but has some useful commands included specially for developers. To open it, just search for it in the Search/Run taskbar:

[image]